# "expected an indented block" which I couldn't figure out

Tags: python, json

Here's my script in python and I got error like this:

```
File "overlap.py", line 5
    for line in infile:
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I couldn't figure out the error, the input is json file download from yelp. The script was coded in vim, I double checked the indentation again and again and it seems nothing wrong here.
Here the code:

```
import json

def cal_overlap(filename = "yelp_academic_dataset_review.json"):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            data = json.loads(line)
            buz = data["business_id"]
            user_id = data["user_id"]
            if user_id in result:
                if buz not in result[user_id]:
                    result[user_id].append(buz)
            else:
                result[user_id] = []
                result[user_id].append(buz)
        return result

def plot(res):
    s = 0
    count = 0
    x = []
    y = []
    for key in res:
        count += 1
        s += len(res[key])
    return float(s) / count

def main():
    res = cal_overlap()
    print plot(res)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: vim/emacs like to replace 8 spaces with single tab, did you double check that you only have real spaces? that being said, python interprets 1 tab as 8 spaces, so that should not be the cause of your problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing tabs and spaces in your indentation. That might account for the indentation looking right to you but not to the interpreter.

Stick to using all spaces for your indentation.

*Edit:*

If you are using a shebang in your python scripts, you can specify the argument `-tt` to check if you are using a mixture of tabs and spaces in your indentation.

E.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -tt
```

Comment: thanks. But is there better solution instead keep tapping white spaces for indentation?

Comment: Use a different code editor, if that's your problem.

Comment: I see. How could I check the mixture of tabs and spaces? Could you explain more w/ examples. I don't quite get that.

Comment: If you are not on a unixy system, the stuff about [shebangs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is irrelevant. But basically if you use the argument `-tt` when you are calling your python interpreter, it will tell you "You're mixing tabs and spaces and you need to fix it."

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem at `for line in infile:`, but your second-last line is wrong:

```
if __name__ = '__main__':
```

needs to read

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

I fixed that and the module compiles fine.

Comment: Thanks. But "=" is a typo. I changed that in my post. It works now by changing every tab in python to 4 white space indentation. But I don't know why since my tab is also 4 white space indentation.

Comment: @f4fc2791e4473eb2ba41b5ddb445b2: and it works fine for me. Are you sure you are running this in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a mix of tabs and spaces in your code? Just use all spaces for your indentation otherwise you'll get some strange errors.